# Angularjs not rendering some pages

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using angularjs in my projects, everything is working fine, every page is loading correctly, but only 3 pages in my script that are not loading and giving me this error.

```
[Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: /path_to/pace.min.js :: RequestIntercept/monitorXHR/req.open :: line 420"  data: no]
RequestIntercept/monitorXHR/req.open()pace.min.js (line 420)
ye/<()angular.min.js (line 78)
s()angular.min.js (line 74)
q/f<()angular.min.js (line 71)
Ae/e/l.promise.then/E()angular.min.js (line 100)
Ae/e/l.promise.then/E()angular.min.js (line 100)
Ae/f/<.then/<()angular.min.js (line 101)
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval()angular.min.js (line 112)
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest()angular.min.js (line 109)
Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply()angular.min.js (line 112)
Wd/this.$get</<()angular.min.js (line 90)
jQuery.event.dispatch()jquery.js (line 4664)
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle()
```

I am using pacejs too, but that is not the problem, it was not even working before I implemented pacejs.

And these 3 pages are working fine in chrome, but its not working in Firefox only.

Please tell me the possible reasons for this errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Any code snippet to debug?

Comment: well I think this is not about the code, this is about the browser compatibility. Current Firefox version is 38.0.5.